# Select true last cell of filtered data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to select the true last cell data set then insert a subtotal into the cell below. Everything I've tried selects the last cell of my visible data. I need the last cell of the entire sheet.

For instance, my filtered data will have rows 3:10 visible. My code is selecting row 10 when I need it to select the last row of the entire dataset that's hidden (row 100).

This will be performed on multiple sheets at once.

Here's my code:

```
Sub Example()

Dim LastRow As Long

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Range("J2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

End With

Call SubTotalMacro

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Find the last row before filtering and store in a variable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586848/get-last-row-from-filtered-range

Comment: Wow, not sure how that didn't cross my mind. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`MsgBox ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row`

Comment: A note: `UsedRange` is not reliable. It may extend past where the user expects it to stop. More discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Comment: Is it also risky in @cpaneedhelp's case?

Comment: It could be, yes.